# Nginx reverse proxy not passing some pages to app server

Tags: nginx, static, reverse-proxy, proxypass, otrs

I have a NGINX server running as a reverse proxy to a OTRS app server.

```
upstream otrs_server {
        server X.X.X.X;
}


server {
        listen 17031;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/otrs.access.log;

        location / {
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                default_type  application/octet-stream;
                sendfile        on;
                keepalive_timeout  65;
                gzip  on;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://otrs_server;
         }

}
```

I can see the login page of the OTRS app server, and some pages are getting delivered when i check `/var/log/nginx/otrs.access.log`

```
 [26/Apr/2016:11:47:56 +0200] "GET /otrs/index.pl HTTP/1.1" 200 3951 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36"
```

But all the CSS and logos are missing, and I can see also the errors in the `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

```
2016/04/26 11:47:56 [error] 2353#2353: *279897 open() "/etc/nginx/html/otrs-web/skins/Agent/KIX4OTRS/css-cache/img/logo.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), request: "GET /otrs-web/skins/Agent/KIX4OTRS/css-cache/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1", referrer: "http://X.X.X.X:17031/otrs/index.pl"
```

nginx is using **/etc/nginx/html/** instead of **http://X.X.X.X:17031** for some static pages.

Anyone has an idea why that happens?

Comment: I would guess that the OTRS app server doesn't know that it is being proxied behind port 17031 and is generating content with references to the default port.